# Remote config menu item missing

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, firebase-remote-config

Following this guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android/start/

Where the instructions state "Select Remote Config from the menu to view the Remote Config dashboard."

I don't have that item in the dashboard:

[image]

I'm probably missing something obvious, but hey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the "Grow" section of the menu on the left.  It's closer to the bottom and you have have to scroll the menu down to see it.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks.

It should really be in "Develop", and it looks like it used to be there according to 
https://segunfamisa.com/posts/firebase-remote-config

Answer (score 0):

it is inside here, check engage section, maximize it. you can see the firebase config
[image]